# RNG state not getting preserved while using get_randstate and set_randstate

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to understand why in the following example, the RNG state is not getting preserved:

```
module test;
  string Seed_s = "0";
  int unsigned Seed_i = 0;

  initial
  begin
    process p;
    p = process::self();
    $display("Process randstate1 = ", p.get_randstate());
    Seed_s = p.get_randstate();
    $display("Process Seed_s = %s", Seed_s);
    Seed_i = Seed_s.atobin();
    $display("Process Seed_s = %s", Seed_s);
    $display("Process randstate2 = %d", Seed_i);
    p.set_randstate(Seed_s);
    $display("Process randstate3 = ", p.get_randstate());
  end
endmodule
```

Here's the output:

```
Process randstate1 = 0000000000000000000000000000000000001001011001101001101001011110
Process randstate2 =  157719134
Process randstate3 = 0X1Z00ZZXZX011Z00X0ZX01XZXZ0X111XZZXZZZXZXZXZZXZZZZXZZZZXXXXXXXX
```

I expected to see randstate1 = randstate3. What am I missing here?

EDIT: Added a display string before and after the atobin()

```
Process randstate1 = 0000000000000000000000000000000000001001011001101001101001011110
Process Seed_s = 0000000000000000000000000000000000001001011001101001101001011110
Process Seed_s = 0000000000000000000000000000000000001001011001101001101001011110
Process randstate2 =  157719134
Process randstate3 = 0X1Z00ZZXZX011Z00X0ZX01XZXZ0X111XZZXZZZXZXZXZZXZZZZXZZZZXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a simulator bug.  What simulator do you use?

When I create a simplified version of your code, and I run it with the Cadence Incisive simulator, I get the same state before and after `set_randstate`:

```
module tb;

string Seed_s;

initial begin
    process p;
    p = process::self();
    $display("Process randstate = ", p.get_randstate());
    Seed_s = p.get_randstate();
    p.set_randstate(Seed_s);
    $display("Process randstate = ", p.get_randstate());
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
Process randstate = svseed=1 ; 3130931317 ; 
Process randstate = svseed=1 ; 3130931317 ;
```

When I run using Synopsys VCS, I get similar results to yours.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine in Questa, producing the following output

```
 # Process randstate1 = MS47527bb5f9e2c20661d2ea9091ed841d
 # Process randstate2 =          0
 # Process randstate3 = MS47527bb5f9e2c20661d2ea9091ed841d
```

I'm guessing your simulator has a bug executing `Seed_s.atobin();` I would display the value of `Seed_s` before and after that.

Comment: Added display statements. Seed_s value remains unchanged